# "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySql environment and installed :
MySQL with the following commands:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
```

and also installed mysql workbench.

But when I'm trying to connect my localhost getting the follow error:

"Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

[image: Error Screenshot]

and even this is the first time I'm posting a question in stackoverflow, sorry for my presentation errors and syntax.

Comment: I have the same problem with 5.7.22. 5.7.21 works fine

Comment: @igor I have it on 5.7.21, specifically running against Dockerised 8.0.11 server with 5.7.21 client, downgrading my Docker image to match the client version sidestepped the issue. It is a version mismatch problem between the client and the server versions.

Comment: same here also using the dockerised 8.01 image

Comment: @ISparkes thanks, updating mysql client version helped me.

Answer (score 42):

So I found the reason for that error message (at least for my case).
It's because MySQL as of version 8.04 and onwards uses `caching_sha2_password` as default authentication plugin where previously `mysql_native_password` has been used.

This obviously causes compatibility issues with older services that expect `mysql_native_password` authentication.

Solutions:

1. Check for an updated version of the client service you are
   using (most recent workbench for instance).
2. Downgrade the MySQL Server to a version below that change.
3. Change the authentication plugin on a per user basis (I didn't find a global option, maybe there exists one though).

Now regarding option 3 this is as simple as altering the user:

```
ALTER USER user
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'pw';
```

or when creating the user:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

[See MySQL Server Blog](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/)

[See Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html)

Comment: When attempting option 3 the message I got after was 'No errors 0 rows affected' So I don't think it did anything.

Comment: I also received the "0 rows affected" message but it did update the user and I was able to connect.

Answer (score 12):

Some more details coming here:
That `caching_sha2_password` plugin is the new default authentication plugin on MySQL 8 server. Only the libmysql library from that MySQL 8 distribution owns this plugin, and it is *built statically* into libmysql - the C-connector for various clients. That `caching_sha2_password` is [not available separately for downloading](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,664655,664726#msg-664726).

This is the very first time that libmysql has an important plugin statically included. And this causes any other libmysql (including libmariadb and also older libmysql's) not to connect to MySQL 8 with a user which is defined to use that `caching_sha2_password` authentication.

I just hope that the guys from MariaDB are so nice to also include that `caching_sha2_password` in their libmariadb, to restore the drop-in-compatibility between MySQL and MariaDB.

From MySQL's [server blog](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-4-new-default-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password/):

> Support for caching_sha2_password was added in MySQL 8.0.3. Older
>   versions of libmysqlclient do not support this plugin. So, although
>   client tools that use libmysqlclient older than one available with
>   MySQL 8.0.3 can connect to MySQL 8.0.4 server using users that use
>   other authentication plugins such as mysql_native_password or
>   sha256_password, **such client cannot connect to MySQL 8.0.4 server
>   using users which require caching_sha2_password support.** For an
>   upgraded database, it means connecting using an existing user account
>   should not face any issues.

Comment: Note:  This also means it is very difficult to use any 32-bit MS Windows client with MySQL 8.0.3 whatsoever since they forcefully disallow source compilation of the Connector/C libraries for 32-bit windows.

Comment: It's important to know because in most distro Linux, like Debian 9, when we configure the package management, we get Mysql 8.0.1X. So we can to use use mysql_native_password at my.cnf file.

Comment: Note that meanwhile MariaDB provides 32 + 64 bit versions of that `caching_sha2_password` plugin, in the `lib/plugin/` folder of their [server downloads](https://downloads.mariadb.com/MariaDB/).

Answer (score 8):

In the my.cnf file add the following line:

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

then restart the server.

Comment: IMHO the sha2 caching password plugin transition across the whole MySQL/MariaDB/PHP/etc landscape has been terribly implemented. It's confusing and frustrating. Your answer is unorthodox but got me back up and running quick.

Answer (score 4):

The latest MYSQL versions have 'caching_sha2_password' as the default authentication type. Which does not allow remote connections to MYSQL and results in caching_sha2_password plugin error.
I have fixed it using

> **ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'yourpassword';**

Now it allows your user to access MySQL from localhost.

If you want to access MySQL from multiple remote hosts then do the following,
**

> **ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY
> 'youpassword';**

**
After every alter command in SQL run the following to take effect.

> **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

OR restart MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

Login to Mysql or your workbench, and run the following statement for any user who has this issue:

```
alter USER 'YOURUSERFORMYSQL'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'YOURPASSWORD'
```

In case you did not create the user yet, you can activate this feature during the user creation.

```
create USER 'NEWUSER'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'NEWPASSWORD'
```