# Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) MySQL "no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries"

Tags: mysql, docker, apple-silicon

I'm running the latest build of the [Docker Apple Silicon Preview.](https://www.docker.com/blog/download-and-try-the-tech-preview-of-docker-desktop-for-m1/) I created the tutorial container/images and it works fine. When I went to create a custom YAML file and run docker-compose I get the following error when pulling mysql:

ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries

Here is a snippet from my YAMl file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql-server:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp
    networks:
      - wpsite
```

I've tried :latest and :8 which result in the same error. It pulls phpmyadmin and wordpress fine.

Comment: And *have* the MySQL maintainers pushed an image for that architecture?

Comment: There are only amd64 images... [mysql Tags \- Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated)

Comment: Strange, I believe MySQL supports ARM
Source: https://mysqlonarm.github.io/Running-MySQL-on-ARM/

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI
https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated (server) looks the same but that will install.

Comment: @Sam `mysql-server:5.7` version is quite too old to support arm64! https://hub.docker.com/layers/mysql/mysql-server/5.7/images/sha256-96f7f199868eaaf9dd9c3cff47021831f5525047b41b0c6a8bf1187936a3e9d2?context=explore

Comment: Where a `linux/amd64` image is available, I believe this is the underlying issue: https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3225

Comment: Checkout second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361161/316343 if you're not looking specifically for mysql.

Answer (score 822, accepted):

Well, technically it will not solve your issue (running MySQL on ARM), but for the time being, you could add `platform` to your service like:

```
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    ...
```

Alternatively, consider using MariaDB, which should work as a drop-in replacement like e.g. this:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5.8
    ...
```

Both ways work for me on M1 with the Docker Preview

Comment: Same thing i did for "percona" image(mysql on steroids) also.  Thank you!

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/
I see the documentation has been updated to include instructions for running under emulation (platform linux/amd64 flag) and to encourage mariadb support.

Comment: For docker (without compose) you can do: `docker run --platform linux/x86_64 mysql` which pulls and runs the correct images on an M1 too. Thank you so much for this post!

Comment: Can i suggest you to change the mysql version to 8 ? 
The edit is to short for be submitted

Comment: Is there a way to set an image based on the current arch in the docker compose file? Say, use mysql if running on x86 or use mariadb if running on arm?

Comment: @jibeeeee, the original question asked about mysql5.7 . You can probably just use mysql-server:8.0 or whichever version you prefer.

Comment: Can our employers with Intel i7 use same configuration?

Comment: @AlexShtromberg - this should work also on Intel machines, as it's a x86 architecture...

Comment: Worked just fine with Mac OS running under Apple Silicon M1. Thank you!

Comment: The alternative you suggested, `mariadb` container worked great apple silicon / arm

Comment: Adding `platform: linux/x86_64` resolved the problem for me on an M1 Mac.

Comment: As this seems to be an accepted answert, I wanted to add, that updating a version to something like ``mysql:5.7.34`` might already fix the issue. I have rosetta2 and docker with m1 support installed.

Comment: MariaDB is not a drop-in replacement (anymore). Since MySQL 5.7, versions are deviating to the point where restoring dumps made with `mysqldump` on MySQL 5.7 will not restore on MariaDB anymore. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54875134/moving-to-mariadb-from-mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed

Comment: this solution add platform in docker-compose is perfect, simple and solve my problem

Comment: i was with the same problem with sonarqube image and this works for me

Comment: FWIW, neither this nor *any* of the answers to this question worked for me (I got the same error as the OP).  My machine is an M1 MBP with the M1 Max chip.  As far as my personal experience goes, it is still impossible to run MySQL under Docker, both with and without emulation, in late 2022.  It's hard for me to believe that no one has successfully compiled and published MySQL for M1.

Comment: I tried to use this solution in my docker-compose file, but my CMS app was locally very slow and pages took more than 10 sec. to load (also docker desktop shown that I might have slow perf with this container)... Then I removed platform, updated to MySQL 8, and there was no issue for me - it loads in tens of milliseconds again...

Comment: I experienced the same problem with my Mac M2 machine and this resolved it

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/67361161/316343 if you're not looking specifically for mysql.

Answer (score 314):

same problem for m1 mac just run this command

```
docker pull --platform linux/x86_64 mysql
```

Comment: worked on mac mini m1 altough I had to add v8: `linux/x86_64/v8`

Comment: Worked for me MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)

Comment: Also worked for me on M2: `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/x86_64/v8`

Comment: M2 PRO: `export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`

Answer (score 177):

From [this answer](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318#issuecomment-783340346), I added this to my local `docker-compose.override.yml`

```
services:

  mysql:
    platform: linux/amd64
```

Comment: this actually made it for me. m1 pro 14''

Comment: M1 pro, tried the answers above, no luck, but this one worked for me

Comment: I also changed mysql version 5.7.22 to 5.7

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: worked on simple Apple Silicon M1

Comment: thank you. this worked for me on an Oracle ARM-based Ampere A1 VM instance

Comment: It worked on M2 mac mini

Answer (score 64):

Oracle maintains a MySQL 8.0.23 docker image for arm64.
https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server

To use it in your docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mycontainername
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabasename
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
    command: --lower_case_table_names=1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Mac Mimi M1, thank you!

Comment: I also used `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/52789430/332798

Comment: worked fine to me to. MacBook Pro m1

Comment: Worked for me. Mac Air M1 2020 Big Sur.
I tried the chose answer but I was warned that emulating linux/x86_64 could generate errors ou memory overhead.
Thank U very much.

Comment: This did not work for me at all.  I got the same error ("no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries") as the OP.  I also tried setting the platform to "linux/amd64", "linux/x86_64", and "linux/x86_64/v8", and still received the same error.  It looks like it's still impossible to run MySQL under Docker, with and without emulation, even in September of 2022.  I can't believe no one anywhere has compiled MySQL for M1.

Comment: @Aquarelle clearly there is something wrong with your setup because I and countless others are running MySQL perfectly fine (with and without emulation) on Apple M1 processors. It you took a moment to read the Dockerfile for the image I mentioned above, you'd see Oracle explicitly says its compiled for ARM. https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server

Comment: @bpossolo Forgive the angry rant.  I may even delete my comment, if that's possible.  The issue was entirely PEBKAC (I had been pointing docker compose at an old, outdated compose file in a shell script, and I didn't realize it until a couple hours ago, at which point I facepalmed and then updated the script).  Everything's working beautifully now.  Sorry!

Comment: glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 43):

Docker on its official documentation says:

> Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add
> `--platform linux/amd64` to run an Intel image under emulation. In
> particular, the mysql image is not available for ARM64. You can work
> around this issue by using a mariadb image.

(source [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues))

So what you should do to make your project work is to add `platform: linux/amd64` to your docker-compose.yml.

It would look like:

```
services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        platform: linux/amd64
        ...
```

As you can imagine probably the performance won't be the same.

Answer (score 39):

I had a similar issue, solved with this line in my dockerfile:

before

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
```

after

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 ubuntu:18.04
```

Comment: This workd great you just have to add this to your mysql docker file for laradock FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

Answer (score 29):

You just need to specify the platform after specifying the *image*. Working on M2 processor

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql-server:5.7
    platform: linux/amd64 <--------- this line to add
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp
    networks:
      - wpsite
```

Comment: Thanks, this works on M1 too. This is interesting, so it makes it work through Rosetta?

Answer (score 23):

## Only Developer with Mac (M1)

I am the only one with Mac (M1 chip) in my team. All others have Windows, so if I want to be compatible with others in git I need to use a solution that isolates the part of the config relating to my machine.

### The Approach

To add more configurations but use a different file, create a new docker-compose file `docker-compose.mac.yml` in the same directory as the normal one `docker-compose.yml`. (Instead of the word mac can be used anything)

### The Code

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.26
    platform: linux/amd64
```

Then start it with this command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.mac.yml up
```

### How it Works

It will copy everything from `docker-compose.yml` file and paste it into `docker-compose.mac.yml` file but without replacing.

In my opinion, it is super useful in a bigger teams with different computers.

Comment: Thank you!
If you use the name `docker-compose.override.yml` for the file, it will be picked up automatically by docker-compose. This way you can use the standard docker-compose commands without needing the `-f` flags.

Answer (score 21):

This works for me in mac M1, specifying platform key inside service.

```
services:
  mysql:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

Answer (score 14):

For anyone struggling to make it work with a specific version, the following didn't work for me:

```
docker run --platform linux/x86_64 mysql:5.7.26 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

but this did:

```
 docker run --platform linux/x86_64 mysql:5.7 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

Answer (score 11):

can try start/run a container (for mac m1)

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name mysql --platform linux/x86_64 --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345 mysql
```

Answer (score 10):

In your `Dockerfile` for mysql if you have the following

`FROM mysql:8.0.28`

change it to

`FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 mysql:8.0.28`

because the Docker in Apple M1 is going to look for an ARM image, and MySQL doesn't publish ARM images, so that's why you are getting

> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB
> definition: no match for platform in manifest

with the `--platform` flag, even though we are in ARM processor we are telling docker that we want to use the `x86_64` image

Answer (score 9):

I have a similar issue with the M1 chip. This is because some images don’t support the new Apple M1 Chip.

If you are getting this error "no matching manifest for Linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries" on the Apple M1 Silicon chip using Docker Compose.

Add the **platform: linux/amd64** in your docker-compose.yml

Modifying the yml file above:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql-server:5.7
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp
      MYSQL_USER: wp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp
    networks:
      - wpsite
```

Answer (score 8):

[Please refer to the following link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-m1/#known-issues) for known issues. In your Mac's terminal run

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

and then in docker-compose have something along the lines of

```
mysql_gdpr:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "user_security"
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_USER: "security"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pleasechangeit"
```

Comment: Just Adding `platform: linux/x86_64` does the trick.

Comment: Rosetta is the way to go, thanks! https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: platform: linux/x86_64 does the trick

Answer (score 5):

To resolve the issue, we need to pass the **platform** with value into your docker image/file.

Using **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    ...
```

Using **Docker** file:

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 mysql:5.7
```

Using **docker pull** command:

```
docker pull --platform=linux/x86_64 mysql:5.7
```

Using **DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM** parameter:

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/x86_64
```

Some of other well known platforms are: `linux/amd64`, `linux/arm64` etc.

Comment: dumb question from a non docker expert. Where do you run export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 ?

Comment: Hi @Sayf you need to export before running your script from shell script or command prompt.

Answer (score 5):

- In my M1-Pro chip, worked with this command.

`docker run --platform linux/amd64 --name mysql-5-7 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:5.7`

Comment: best solution when I am building from a remote repo from github without cloning the whole thing locally to alter docker compose

Answer (score 3):

Using this below image solved my problem.

```
mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that when using `--platform linux/x86_64` on arm64/v8 you may lose [Linux Native AIO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-linux-native-aio.html) support.

Check out the docker container logs:

```
[ERROR] [MY-012585] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO interface is not supported on this platform. Please check your OS documentation and install appropriate binary of InnoDB.
[Warning] [MY-012654] [InnoDB] Linux Native AIO disabled.
```

Consider using [mysql/mysql-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server) instead, as it has arm64/v8 support out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

This [Github repo](https://github.com/nanhantianyi/docker-mysql-5.7-aarch64) allows to build a MySQL 5.7 aarch64 image.

Building it with the following command (naming it the same as the official mysql:5.7 image) it will be used by default by all your docker-compose configurations or Dockerfiles that specify mysql:5.7.

```
docker build -t mysql:5.7 .
```

It means that you won't have updates from the official MySQL Dockerhub repo anymore, but as a temporary drop-in replacement I find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

I've also encountered this issue on M1 Pro and to solve the most stable way for me was to disable buildkit in the Docker engine settings, meaning setting to false instead the default true. There is also an open issue here https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5873

Answer (score 2):

Look at this github [post](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318#issuecomment-1082783231)

Since "Oracle only supplies pre-compile Arm64" binaries, you have it there with

Image --> mysql:8.0-oracle

> docker run -d --name mysql-8 -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<your_password> mysql:8.0-oracle

Answer (score 2):

Change the platform in docker command

Param : --platform linux/x86_64

Answer (score 2):

This is for anyone who is here for the same issue but with the ibmcom/db2

You can use the below command to pull the db2 image

```
docker pull --platform linux/x86_64 ibmcom/db2:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

Attempts to run x86 containers on M1 machines under emulation can crash. Even when the containers do run correctly under emulation, they will be slower and use more memory than the native equivalent. From here https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues

Answer (score -1):

I have the M1 chip.

Today I found this works fine in the latest KSQL master branch. Here's the commands

```
git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql.git
cd ksql
docker-compose up -d
```

It magically brings up the Zookeeper, three instances of Kafka server, a Schema Registry and a CLI.

Reference:
[KSQLDB Docker Guide](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/installing/)