# docker run mysql image command not working [MacBook Pro M1]

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, containers, apple-silicon

I was following the official docker labs hands-on tutorial for multi-container apps tutorials.
While running the below command on **MacBook Pro M1** terminal

```
docker run -d `
    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql `
    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql `
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret `
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos `
    mysql:5.7
```

I am getting the below error.

> docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list
> entries.

Comment: Please help to share your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 25):

If anyone else runs into this issue while following the guide on a Mac M1 machine specifically, the quickest work-around is probably to add the flag:

```
--platform linux/amd64
```

like

```
docker run -d \
    --platform linux/amd64 \
    --network todo-app --network-alias mysql \
    -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
    mysql:5.7
```

Credits to
https://github.com/docker/getting-started/issues/144

Comment: This seems to work for a M1 Macbook Pro

Answer (score 3):

When you check the offical [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated) image, you can see there is no mention of `linux/arm64/v8`

In the case of `mysql` [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/#known-issues) even states that:

> Not all images are available for ARM64 architecture. You can add --platform linux/amd64 to run an Intel image under emulation. In particular, the mysql image is not available for ARM64. You can work around this issue by using a mariadb image.

So you could use [mariadb](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated) as a workaround, until they offer official support for `mysql` like so:

```
docker run -d \
  -v todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql \
  -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret \
  -e MYSQL_DATABASE=todos \
  mariadb:10.5
```

See: [github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318)

If you really need the mysql image you could try the workaround mentioned in the same issue [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318#issuecomment-783340346). As of now I can't test this, because I don't have an m1 macbook.

Comment: I saw this already as part of my research before posting this. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65456814/6572971

Answer (score 1):

Incase you are using docker compose for your container ochestration you can have your `docker-compose.yaml` file mirror something similar to this

```
services:
  mysql:
  platform: linux/amd64
  #you can use whatever image you prefer
  image: "mysql:5.7"
```