# No Matching Manifest Error when using Sail on Laravel

Tags: laravel, macos, docker, apple-m1, laravel-sail

I am attempting to setup a basic project in Laravel using Laravel Sail.  According to the [official Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#getting-started-on-macos) the following commands will create a new Laravel application called "example-app" and start Laravel Sail.

```
curl -s "https://laravel.build/example-app" | bash
cd example-app
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

However, after running these commands I see the following error message:

```
ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error occurs when using Laravel Sail on Macs with the Apple M1 chip.  The docker-compose file provided by Laravel Sail uses MySQL by default.  As configured, the docker-compose file is attempting to use an unknown version of MySQL (linux/arm64/v8).  This fails with the error message above.

This can be solved by opening the docker-compose.yml file in the Laravel project root folder, searching the section named mysql and adding the following below the `image:` line

```
platform: 'linux/amd64'
```

Adding this line will run an Intel image under emulation on the Mac M1.  You can read some background information about this in the official [Docker document about Apple Silicon](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8).

If possible for your use case this can also be resolved by switching the image to MariaDB instead of MySQL.  MariaDB is basically binary compatible with MySQL.  Using MariaDB may be a better option if possible because, as mentioned in the Docker document

> Attempts to run Intel-based containers on Apple Silicon machines under
> emulation can crash as qemu sometimes fails to run the container.

Using the MySQL container in emulation on an M1 Mac could cause issues such as a segmentation fault when starting Sail - in fact I saw this issue in one case.  Switching to MariaDB resolved this.  You can switch Laravel Sail to MariaDB instead of MySQL by changing the `image:` line for the mysql service in the docker-compose.yml file to:

`image: 'mariadb'`

Answer (score 1):

Posted this on Github thought I'll leave it here as well https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/38370

```
Laravel Version: 8.54.0
PHP Version: 8.0
Database Driver & Version: MySQL 8
MacOS: Big Sur 11.5.2
```

Mac M1 Docker Laravel  Sail MySQL 8 won't pull arm arch
The example app won't "sail up" (docker-compose up) on M1 chips

Error:

```
Pulling mysql (mysql:8.0)...
8.0: Pulling from library/mysql
ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fc0a4a7400cf528d05fd5660ffe8db372c50baa9/docker-compose.yml#L9

An easy fix would be to use MariaDB instead:

docker-compose.yml:

```
    mysql:
        image: 'mariadb'
```

Done

If you really need MySQL:

Recommended by docker, wasn't needed on my end.

Open up a Terminal ->
`softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

Docker-compose.yml

```
    mysql:
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
```

After that, the correct MySQL image will be pulled.

```
sail up

Pulling mysql (mysql/mysql-server:8.0.23)...
8.0.23: Pulling from mysql/mysql-server
```

Done

other links:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/apple-silicon/
[Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) MySQL "no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8)