# Laravel sail failed to start

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I am trying to start laravel sail on Mac M1. I was able to resolve mysql version issue. Now when I run `.vendor/bin/sail up` command it get stuck at `[4/12] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl`. These are last commands before the error apperas

```
#8 133.9 Fetched 25.3 MB in 10s (2488 kB/s)
#8 134.0 Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 21562 files and directories currently installed.)
#8 134.0 Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.3.0-deb-1nodesource1_arm64.deb ...
#8 134.0 Unpacking nodejs (16.3.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
#8 135.7 Setting up nodejs (16.3.0-deb-1nodesource1) ...
#8 135.7 Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
#8 135.8 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
#8 136.8 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
#8 136.8 Segmentation fault
```

This error is displayed in the end.

```
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev        php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd        php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached        php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring        php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap        php8.0-intl php8.0-readline        php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap        php8.0-redis     && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*]: exit code: 2
ERROR: Service 'laravel.test' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: I saw 1 more post about this also. It was giving error for `gnupg` and `gosu`. No idea about this as I have my own `docker-compose` to prevent this type of issues. What I am trying to say is that, maybe, it is a general problem.

Comment: This issue came recently before that sail was working properly. And then suddenly it started showing error. I have also reinstalled docker in case that was creating an issue. I also have tried many laravel docker-compose but of no use. Can you share your docker-compose? It can help me to point out the issue.

Comment: The error is clearly related to the image it is using, in this case `ubuntu` (I think), so it is not related to docker or anything like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Matching Manifest Error when using Sail on Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67948804/no-matching-manifest-error-when-using-sail-on-laravel)

Comment: No this solution doesn't work

Comment: @HumAizShahid I had this issue and found the fix in a closed issue on laravel/sail. You need to downgrade Docker until the issue is resolved. https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/159#issuecomment-863079097

Answer (score 0):

According to this closed issue on the laravel/sail repo, the fix as of this posting is to downgrade Docker. This fixed the issue for me.

https://github.com/laravel/sail/issues/159#issuecomment-863079097

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had same problem and for me problem was in Composer i had to update Composer to Composer 2, somehow WSL2 Ubuntu comes with wrong version.