# Docker sh error : session ended very soon after starting. why?

Tags: docker

i have to lunch docker and start the sh file. but i got this error. [(terminal window error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOFB0.png), i have a directory with docker-compose file and 2 sh files, after  lunching docker, what could i do to resolve it?

error : Docker sh error :  session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in profile "Default" is correct.

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile and the command you run and the logs.

Comment: Including the error in the question (as text, not behind a link) would be really helpful too.

Comment: hi, i finally founed a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8