# 'No matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries' for elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, apple-m1

Running docker on Apple Silicon/M1 and currently getting this error when performing **docker-compose up -d**

`no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`

This error was originally showing for my mysql_db too however I went into the docker-compose.yml file and added  -

```
mysql_db:
   restart: always
   platform: linux/x86_64
```

When trying to add the same line under api_elasticsearch in my docker-compose.yml, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is saying that the Elasticsearch container doesn't support ARM. The platform directive doesn't work for all images

Comment: Yes but is there not a work around for this?

Comment: I think would require talking to Elasticsearch Docker maintainers

Comment: What image is this? I.e. the specific image name you're having a problem with?

Comment: Possible duplicate, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8)