# Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) goaws (no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries)

Tags: docker, macos, docker-compose, apple-m1

I am using Apple M1 Pro

I am getting the following error when i try to run **docker-compose up -d**

```
[+] Running 0/1
 ⠿ goaws Error                                                                                                                                                                                             3.9s
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

I tried to add **platform: linux/amd64** to the docker-compose.yml file and run again. But it doesn't work.

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8), they used platform: linux/x86_64. not platform: linux/amd64, maybe that could be the issue?