# docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries. with zookeeper

Tags: docker, apache-zookeeper

I was trying to setup the zookeeper locally by following: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kafka-connect-fundamentals/table-of-contents.

How to fix this?

```
docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 zookeeper:3.5.5 --platform linux/x86_64
Unable to find image 'zookeeper:3.5.5' locally
3.5.5: Pulling from library/zookeeper
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I tried several options [Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) MySQL "no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8), but unfortunately none of them worked

Answer (score 0):

You've linked to a mysql post, when zookeeper has its own Docker tags, which you can find on DockerHub. Zookeeeper 3.5.5 image simply doesn't support ARM platform.

Otherwise, you can use latest `confluentinc/cp-zookepeer` tags (after 7.3.1) which support ARM64