# docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, apple-m1

First I tried to install the rust cross command on my M1 mac:

```
 cargo install -f cross
```

then using this command to cross compile the application:

```
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

facing the error:

```
> cross build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
[cross] warning: using newer rustc `1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)` for the target. Current active rustc on the host is `rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)`.
 > Update with `rustup update`
info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-musl'
info: installing component 'rust-std' for 'x86_64-unknown-linux-musl'
 35.8 MiB /  35.8 MiB (100 %)  18.3 MiB/s in  1s ETA:  0s
Unable to find image 'ghcr.io/cross-rs/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl:0.2.5' locally
0.2.5: Pulling from cross-rs/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
docker: no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

what should I do to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead

```
docker pull --platform linux/amd64 ghcr.io/cross-rs/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl:0.2.5
```

I had similar problem and reading this ([Docker (Apple Silicon/M1 Preview) MySQL "no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8)) helped me figure it out