# Error while installing / running Apache Superset using Docker on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, arm, apple-m1, apache-superset

I followed the steps to install Apache Superset using Docker as mentioned on Superset's Installation guide [here](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose#1-install-a-docker-engine-and-docker-compose)
I then did a `cd superset` and then `docker compose up`. This is what I get:

```
WARN[0000] The "CYPRESS_CONFIG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "CYPRESS_CONFIG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Running 3/6
 
⠴ superset-tests-worker Pulling 3.6s                                        
 ! superset-websocket Warning    1.2s                                                     
 ⠴ superset-worker-beat Pulling  3.6s                                                  
 ⠴ superset-init Pulling         3.6s                                                      
 ✘ superset-worker Error         3.6s                                                     
 ✘ superset Error                3.6s                                                                 
no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
```

Can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Run it with emulation using `--platform=linux/amd64`

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612).  I would copy-paste your error msg and search to try and help, but ... I can't.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for letting me know. I've removed the image, and pasted the error message.

Comment: @NicoHaase: Yes ofcourse I did. I didn't find anything, which is why I posted the question here.

How is your response helpful? Your opinion of my question is irrelevant.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456814/docker-apple-silicon-m1-preview-mysql-no-matching-manifest-for-linux-arm64-v8 help? It contains that error and some ideas about how to resolve it

Comment: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/25434 even contains hints for running Superset on a M1 pro (which looks pretty close to your use case)

Answer (score 0):

@NicoHasse, Thank you for help, and for this link - github.com/apache/superset/issues/25434.

I performed the following and it worked

```
docker-compose down && docker image prune -a 
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 
docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
```

Really appreciate your help!